# Python :: ctypes :: GetProcAddress() returns error

Tags: c++, python, winapi, ctypes

The following is a part of a debugger class. I've got the following code for enumerating processes in debugee. First it enumerates and loads handles of the existing debugee's processes into an array. Then I'm trying to get an address of particular function in particular module. In this case i'm trying to get address of **printf()** out of **msvcr100.dll**

```
def enumerate_module(self,pid):
```

```
    lphModule = (c_void_p * 1024)()
    lpcbNeeded = c_ulong(0)

    if psapi.EnumProcessModules(self.h_process,lphModule,sizeof(c_void_p)*1024, byref(lpcbNeeded)):
        print "[*] EnumProcessModules: %d modules detected" % int(lpcbNeeded.value / sizeof(c_void_p))
        for i in range(int(lpcbNeeded.value / sizeof(c_void_p))):
            FileName = ""
            ReadBuffer = create_string_buffer(MAX_PATH)
            psapi.GetModuleFileNameExA(self.h_process,lphModule[i],ReadBuffer,MAX_PATH)
            FileName += ReadBuffer.value
            print "[*] %d - 0x%08x - %s" % (i,lphModule[i],FileName)
        address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(lphModule[3],"printf")
        if address == False:
            error = GetLastError()
            print "[*] GetProcAddress() ERROR: %d - %s" % (error, FormatError(error))    
        print "[**] Getting printf() address is: 0x%008x" % address
        return True
    else:
        error = GetLastError()
        print "[*] GetModuleHandleA: %d - %s" % (error, FormatError(error))
        return False
```

For some odd reason I cannot get it to work. GetPorcAddress() returns:

```
ERROR: 126 - The specified module could not be found.
```

Any ideas???

PS.
This might clarify my question a little:
Script output

Enter the PID of the process to attach to: 2476
Opening process: 2476
[*] DebugActiveProcess: 0 - The operation completed successfully.
[*] EnumProcessModules: 4 modules detected
[*] 0 - 0x00400000 - printf.exe
[*] 1 - 0x7c900000 - ntdll.dll
[*] 2 - 0x7c800000 - kernel32.dll
[*] 3 - 0x78aa0000 - MSVCR100.dll
[*] GetProcAddress() ERROR: 126 - The specified module could not be found.
[**] Getting printf() address is: 0x00000000
[*] Finished debugging. Exitng...

As you can see msvcr100.dll is loaded at **0x78aa0000**. As far as I understand 
it should have printf() within its address spaces, where I should be able to 
get its address. Moreover, I loaded up printf.exe in OllyDbg and it showed the same
thing that you see on my script's output, and I was able to see printf() in 
msvcr100.dll's exports list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetProcAddress gets the address of a function in a DLL *loaded in your process*, not in a different process.  You should check out the [Debug Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Per your request about GetProcAddress, my references:

[GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> hModule [in]
>   A handle to the DLL module that contains the function or variable. The **LoadLibrary**, **LoadLibraryEx**, or **GetModuleHandle** function returns this handle.

[LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process....

[LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process....

[GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. The module must have been loaded by the calling process.

Comment: According to msdn: "Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL)." Could not find anything about "loaded in your process". Would you please provide references? In addition, I'm able to access kernel32.dll functions loaded by printf.exe within indicated address space.

Comment: @PSS, you can load kernel32.dll functions because *every* process loads kernel32.dll.  References added above.  If this still doesn't convince you, get SysInternals Process Explorer and see what DLLs are loaded for yourself.

Comment: @PSS - it's not spelled out explicitly in the doc, but the phrase "The LoadLibrary, LoadLibraryEx, or GetModuleHandle function returns this handle" should give a clue.

Comment: Click on the Debug Help Library link and read it. SymFromName would be a good start.

Comment: You should not try to LoadLlibrary the CRT.  This will fail as the CRT verifies that it is being loaded via a manifest.

Comment: @John, true from some versions of the CRT, but the OP is trying to look up the address of a function in another process via a debugger he is writing, and loading symbols is fine.  GetProcAddress is the wrong tool.

Comment: @Mark, what would you suggest I use?

Comment: @PSS, get familiar with the Debug Help Library.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681412(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that means that it can't find that particular DLL on your system. Here's a simple function that will return the printf address:

```
from ctypes import *

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

def resolve_function(dll, func):
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, func)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    return address

address = resolve_function('msvcrt.dll','printf')

print(address)
```

I'm still learning this stuff as well, and I'm not quite sure of the difference between `msvcrt.dll` and `msvcr100.dll`. However, I believe you need to link against `msvcrt.dll` instead and microsoft does some magic to find `msvcrXX.dll`. Take a look at this page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your method will not work due to the fact that GetModuleHandleA() works only with modules initialized by the calling process where I am trying to resolve the procedure address of the process that is being debugged. The difference between msvcrt.dll and msvcr100.dll is not important here. What's important that I could resolve msvcr100.dll as being loaded by debugee with its address in lphModule[3]. Where GetProcAddress() should return function's address within the module. But it does not.